# How to force to open a google play link in google chrome instead of the Play Store app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

In my flutter application, I need to force open a google play store link through google chrome and not through the play store app.
How can I do it? It is possible?
This code keeps opening the link with the Play Store app.

Thanks

```
TextButton(
 onPressed: () async {
     const url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana';
     if(await canLaunch(url)){
       await launch(url);
     }else {
       throw 'Could not launch $url';
     }
   },
   child: const CustomWidget(
     icon: Icons.language,
     label: 'Open a URL',
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is a package for this purpose, It's called  [chrome_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/chrome_launcher) 

first make a launcher:**

```
final chromeLauncher = ChromeLauncher();
```

**then launch the url**

```
chromeLauncher.launchWithChrome(url_here);
```

**you can check what else you can do with it using this [example](https://pub.dev/packages/chrome_launcher/example)**